# Header cell with same length as underlying cells in OpenTBS

Tags: opentbs, ods

I want to have length of header cell (composed of merged cells) equal to amount of underlying generated cells

```
[                               header value                         ]
[cell value 1][cell value 2][cell value 3][cell value 4][cell value 5]
```

I use plugin OpenTBS for TinyButStrong Template Engine. So I added to ods template:

```
[headerCell]
[select11.[select10.c1;block=tbs:cell];block=tbs:row]
```

which produces content

```
[header value][            ][            ][            ][            ]
[cell value 1][cell value 2][cell value 3][cell value 4][cell value 5]
```

How to specify this behaviour to header cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LibreOffice, the horizontal cell merging is define with the XML attribute `table:number-columns-spanned`. See [XML Synopsis](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/xml_synopsis.html#libreoffice_tables)

This attribute can be modified with TBS using the parameter `att`.

Example :

Template:

```
|headerCell[my_field]|
```

PHP:

```
$nb_cell = ...; // retrieve the number of cell to merge horizontaly
$TBS->MergeField('my_field', $nb_cell, false, array(
  'att'=>'table:table-cell#table:number-columns-spanned'
 ));
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I merge XML attribute and display value of headerCell using MergeField() at the same time

Comment: You can use the virtual column `#` than  counts records. Try with  `[select10.#;att=table:table-cell#table:number-columns-spanned]` in the headerCell. See http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#php_mergeblock_counting for more info

Comment: Thank you. Inserted ```[select10.#;att=+table:table-cell#table:number-columns-spanned]``` to the left cell prior headerCell

Comment: When I open document in Excel I see that header cell is not spanned.
 Is it possible horizontal cell merging there?

Comment: @koxt Merged cells cannot be managed in XLSX for now with OpenTBS, because unlike in ODS they are stored appart in XLSX.